# How to Read a JavaScript Object in CDATA

Tags: javascript, object, cdata

I'm trying to read the value of a variable in a JavaScript object that's in a CDATA on a web page. The object is very strange because its in the format a.b.c ... I didn't think it was possible to make a JS object like this, and its probably illegal because it doesn't seem to work outside the CDATA.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
a.b.c = {
    num : 100
};
//]]>
</script>
```

How would you read the value of **num** within CDATA?

Thanks.

Comment: `CDATA` is a just a comment; it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks: CDATA is character data that is not to be interpreted but read as-is by an XHTML parser, in no way it is a comment that should not be interpreted by an HTML parser. This is more than obvious by the question. 'a.b.c' refers to a property set 'c' of a property 'b' of an object 'a' that may be defined somewhere else in the HTML page or in an external script loaded by the page. It won't function if you copy and paste it out of its context.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

```html
<script>

var page = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
var pos = page.indexOf('num') + 5;
var id = page.substring (pos);

document.write (id.split(',')[0]);

</script>
```

In the page that is being searched, the search item ("num") is a string that doesn't appear anywhere else on the page.